# Nil element during .sorted in Swift 3

Tags: sorting, null, swift3

So my problem is that I want to sort *chatList* from greatest to lesser *TimeStamp*. That works fine, the problem is when *lastMessage* is nil.

When is nil, I want to set that element of chatList to the first position and continue the sort.

Is there anyway to tell the sort to put that element in the first index to the first position and keep sorting. If no, then what you guys suggest me to do?

```
var sortedChatList: < Array AbstractChat>{

    get{
        return (chatList?.sorted(by:{
            //here goes the timestamp comparison

            if (($0.lastMessage != nil) && ($1.lastMessage != nil))  {
                return Double($0.lastMessage!.timeStamp)! > Double($1.lastMessage!.timeStamp)!
            }
            else{
                return true
            }
        }))!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nil-coalescing operator to default `nil`'s to distant future.

The following illustrates the idea:

```
import Foundation

let foo: [Date?] = [Date(), nil, Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 100)]

let bar = foo.sorted(by: {
    ($0 ?? Date.distantFuture) > ($1 ?? Date.distantFuture)
})

bar.forEach({
    print("\($0)")
})
```